# Scrapy crawl saved links out of csv or array

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "articlelink"
    allow_domains = ['topart-online.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.topart-online.com/de/Blattzweige-Blatt-und-Bluetenzweige/l-KAT282?seg=1']
    
    BASE_URL = 'https://www.topart-online.com/de/'
#scraping cards of specific category
    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//a[@class="clearfix productlink"]')
        for a in card:
            yield{
                'links': a.xpath('@href').get()
            }

        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="page-link"]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page_url:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url, callback=self.parse)
```

this is my spider which crawls all pages of that category and saves all the productlinks into a csv file when i run in my server "scrapy crawl articlelink -o filename.csv".
now i have to crawl all the links in my csv file for specific information, that arent contained in the card of the productlink clearfix
How do i satrt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i'm glad you've gone and had a look at how to scrape the next pages.

Now with regard to the productean number, this is where yielding a dictionary is cumbersome. You will be better off in almost most scrapy scripts to be using the items dictionary. It's suited to being able to grab elements from different pages which is exactly want to do.

Scrapy extracts data from HTML and the mechanism it suggests to do this is through what they call items. Now scrapy accepts a few different types of ways to put data into some form of object. You can use a bog standard dictionary, but for data that requires modification or isn't that clean almost anything other than a very structured data set from the website you should use items at the least. Item's provides a dictionary like object.

To use the items mechanism in our spider script, we have to instantiate the items class to create an item's object. We then populate that items dictionary with the data we want and then in your particularly case we share this items dictionary across functions to continuing adding data from a different page.

In addition to this we have to declare the item field names as is called. But they are the keys to the items dictionary. We do this through items.py located in the project folder.

### Code Example

#### items.py

```
import scrapy

class TopartItem(scrapy.Item):
    
    title = scrapy.Field()
    links = scrapy.Field()
    ItemSKU = scrapy.Field()
    Delivery_Status = scrapy.Field()
    ItemEAN = scrapy.Field()
```

#### spider script

```
import scrapy
from ..items import TopartItem

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "link"
    allow_domains = ['topart-online.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.topart-online.com/de/Blattzweige-Blatt-und-Bluetenzweige/l-KAT282?seg=1']
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS': ['title','links','ItemSKU','ItemEAN','Delivery_Status'] } 
    def parse(self, response):
        card = response.xpath('//a[@class="clearfix productlink"]')
        
        for a in card:
            items = TopartItem()
            link = a.xpath('@href')
            items['title'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="sn_p01_desc h4 col-12 pl-0 pl-sm-3 pull-left"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['links'] = link.get()
            items['ItemSKU'] = a.xpath('.//span[@class="sn_p01_pno"]/text()').get().strip()
            items['Delivery_Status'] = a.xpath('.//div[@class="availabilitydeliverytime"]/text()').get().strip().replace('/','')
            yield response.follow(url=link.get(),callback=self.parse_item, meta={'items':items})

        last_pagination_link = response.xpath('//a[@class="page-link"]/@href')[-1].get()
        last_page_number = int(last_pagination_link.split('=')[-1])
        for i in range(2,last_page_number+1):
            url = f'https://www.topart-online.com/de/Blattzweige-Blatt-und-Bluetenzweige/l-KAT282?seg={i}'
            yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse)
    

    def parse_item(self,response):
        items = response.meta['items']
        items['ItemEAN'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="productean"]/text()').get().strip()
        yield items
```

### Explanation

First within items.py, we are creating a class called `TopArtItem` because we are inheriting from `scrapy.Item` we can instantiating a field object creation for our item's object. Any field we want to create we give it a name and create the field object by `scrapy.Field()`

Within the spider script we have to import this class `TopArtItem` into our spider script. `from ..items` is a relative import which means from the parent directory of the spider script we want to take something from the items.py.

Now the code will look slightly familiar here. First to create our specific item' dictionary called `items` within the for loop we use `items = TopArtItem()`.

The way to add to the items dictionary is similar to any other python dictionary, the key's in the items dictionary are our fields we created in items.py.

The variable `link` is the link to the specific page. We then grab the data we want which you've seen before.
So when we populate our items dictionary in we need to grab the productean number from the individual pages. We do this by following the link, and the callback is the function we want to send the HTML from the individual page to.

The `meta = {'items',items}` is the way we transfer our items dictionary to that function `parse_item`. We create a meta dictionary, with key called items, and the value is our items dictionary we just created.

We then have created the function `parse_item`. To get access to that items dictionary we must access it through the `response.meta` which holds the meta dictionary we created as we made the request in the previous function. response.meta['items'] is how we acccess our items dictionary, we then have called this `items` as before.

Now we can populate the items dictionary which already has data in it from the previous function and add the productean number to it. We then finally yield that items dictionary to tell scrapy we are done adding data for extraction from this particular card.

To summarise that workflow in the parse function we have a loop and for every loop iteration we are following a link, we extract the four pieces of data first, we then make scrapy follow the specific link and add the 5th piece of data before moving onto the next card in the original html document.

### Additional Information

1. Note, try to use `get()` if you want to grab only one piece of data, and `getall()` for more than one piece of data. This is instead of `extract_first()` and `extract()`. If you look at the scrapy docs, they recommend this. get() is abit more concise and when using `extract()` you weren't always sure whether you'll get a string or a list as the extracted data. `getall` will always give you a list.
2. Recommend that you look up other examples of items in other scrapy scripts. by searching github or other websites. I would recommend once you understand the workflow to read carefully the items page on the docs [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/items.html). It's clear but not example friendly. I think its more understandable when you've created scripts with items a few times.

### Updated next page links

I've replaced the code you had for next_page with a more robust way of getting all the data.

```
last_pagination_link = response.xpath('//a[@class="page-link"]/@href')[-1].get()
last_page_number = int(last_pagination_link.split('=')[-1])
for i in range(2,last_page_number+1):
    url = f'https://www.topart-online.com/de/Blattzweige-Blatt-und-Bluetenzweige/l-KAT282?seg={i}'
    yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse)
```

Here we are creating a variable for the last page and grabbing the number from that. I made this because incase you had pages where there were more than 3 pages.

We are doing a for loop and creating the url for each iteration.  This url has whats called an f-string in it. `f''` This allows us to plant a variable in the string, and to use a for loop to add either a number or anything else into that url. So we are planting the number 2 first into the url which gives us the link to the 2nd page. We then use the variable for the last page + 1, as the range function will only process the lastpage by selecting lastpage+1. To create the 3rd page url. We then follow that 3rd page url too.

Comment: thanks kind sir like always! i'll follow your instructions and read the docs you linked. but i have one more question: i run the code and i this error:AttributeError: "LinkSpider" object has no attribute 'parse_item' can you explain that error from line 19 to me?

Comment: Check the indenting of the parse_items function. It's not within the class. My fault for not indenting correctly in SO. Not something i enjoy having to keep doing when inputting code! Updated code, but just indent the line parse_items four spaces along. That's why it's complaining about there not being parse_item.

Comment: Also just checked the data, you're only scraping 40 items when it should be 51 items. Looks like your code is only scraping from page 1 and page 2. Because you're only extracting the first item from the variable next page. Infact there are two values that that XPATH selector for next_page.

Comment: now it works. i have a new project at work, where i can rebuild a spider and check it out by myself. you helped me so unbelievable much. I got my csv file now, but i recognized there are only 40 items, so there are 20 items missing. And when i import something from the items.py file, do i have to import it always as "from ..items" ? What are the points for? //Edit: i saw you also wrote, i only reach 40 items

Comment: Ive updated the code in the example with another way to get the next page. It allows for more than 3 pages and grabs the require 51 objects.

Comment: You always have to import the class you create in items.py into the spider script. As you are using that class to create the items dictionary. So the line items = TopArtItem(), that class TopArtItem() is within the items.py so it is absolutely necessary to import it.

Comment: As I explained in the code example carefully that from ..items is a relative python import. the .. means search within the parent directory of the script you've put .. into for items.py. So it's searching the parent directory of the scrapy spider script in this case. We then import from that the class we need to create the item's directionary.

Comment: I would appreciate a tick on this answer (on the left hand side of my answer) for the help ive given. If there are other posts you done where you think my answer should be the accepted answer, please tick those as well.

Comment: i added "Attribute" and Values" to my code, it works what is totally great. now i have so formatting problems. im crawling for: <div class="productcustomattrdesc word-break col-6"> Innenverpackung/Stck.: </div>. I get something like ["Karto", "Innenmaß"] i used your strip() method to eliminate the whitespace in front of each value, but i always get: AttributeError: 'list' objec has no attribute 'strip' do i have to split the list first?

Comment: That's because strip() only works on a string, if you're crawling something and getting ['karto','innenmaß"], you can't use strip() on this list. You either have to convert this list into a string, or access one item etc by list[0] or by using a for loop etc.. I'm not sure what the goal of scrape you're doing so it's hard to advise further. It may also be worth asking a seperate question on stackoverflow rather than extending this one.

Comment: I do not create a new one, im already finish cus of your help. that was the lask question i got, but with your comment, i can solve that also.

Comment: Well be sure to ask another question if you get stuck, doesn't sound like you need that help though.